# You do not have permission to run the RECONFIGURE statement

Tags: 2013, 2010, permissions, upgrade, sql

I am attempting to upgrade a SP2010 content database to SP2013.  Once I get to 100% of the `Mount-SPContentDatabase`, etc, I am presented with the error:

> Mount-SPContentDatabase:  user does not have permission to perform this action.  You do not have permission to run the RECONFIGURE statement.

I have searched the net with no luck.  All of the answers I have is to change something in SQL but I have no admin access to SQL and the DBAs are hesitant to change permissions to allow the reconfigure statement.

The farm account is in the Farm Admin group.

Comment: Here is what I have learned since posting this.  I knew it was a permissions issue but what permissions.  I thought my Farm account had full rights.  It appears that my account needs the "sysadmin" permission.  My DBA is not willing to give me these permissions because he doesn't know what the program is trying to reconfigure.  Seems reasonable.  I will keep you abreast.

Comment: Update:  I got the rights and the issue is solved!